# tkinter all radiobuttons get selected when the mouse hovers over it

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button

I'm using Radiobuttons in tkinter and I can select them fine but when the mouse hovers over one of the options it gets selected without me actually clicking the left button on the mouse.

```
from tkinter import *

p = Tk()

def select_months():
    new_window = Toplevel()
    new_window.resizable(width=FALSE, height=FALSE)

    days_label = Label(new_window,text="Select month")
    days_label.grid()

    ycolumn = 0
    xrow = 1

    list_of_months = ["January", "February ", "March ", "April "]
    list_of_months_variable = StringVar()

    # list_of_months_variable.set(None)

    for i in list_of_months:
        Radiobutton(new_window, text=i, variable=list_of_months_variable, value=str(i)).grid(padx=4, row=xrow, column=ycolumn)
        ycolumn += 1

        if ycolumn > 2:
            ycolumn = 0
            xrow += 1

    ok_button = Button(new_window, text="OK", command=new_window.destroy).grid()
        
select_month_label = Label(p,text="which month ? : ").pack(side="left")
select_month_button = Button(p, text="months...", command=select_months).pack()

p.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a funny issue, took a while to debug.
Basically the `select_months()` function finishes. But the window appears with all the placed buttons so it is harder to understand that the function has completed. What happens when a function completes? All the local variables to the function get garbage collected. This means that the reference to `list_of_months_variable` is lost too. That causes some issues with the widgets, can't tell exactly why this (select on hover) happens but the solution is pretty simple.

```py
global list_of_months_variable
```

Add this to your `select_months()` function somewhere before defining the variable (usually at the top of function definition):

```py
def select_months():
    global list_of_months_variable
    new_window = Toplevel()
    # the rest of the code ...
```

Also set `value=0` for the `StringVar`:

```py
list_of_months_variable = StringVar(value=0)
```

so that none of the `Radiobutton`s are pre-selected.

---

I would also suggest this:
I strongly advise against using wildcard (`*`) when importing something, You should either import what You need, e.g. `from module import Class1, func_1, var_2` and so on or import the whole module: `import module` then You can also use an alias: `import module as md` or sth like that, the point is that don't import everything unless You actually know what You are doing; name clashes are the issue.

I strongly suggest following [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Function and variable names should be in `snake_case`, class names in `CapitalCase`. Don't have space around `=` if it is used as a part of keyword argument (`func(arg='value')`) but have space around `=` if it is used for assigning a value (`variable = 'some value'`). Have space around operators (`+-/` etc.: `value = x + y`(except here `value += x + y`)). Have two blank lines around function and class declarations.